# infinite loop in java worker thread defies pausing by ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi all i have a question with a string of fairy lights problem. The program is to is to display a string of fairy lights and infinitely go over the collection of light objects turning them on and off.

I have implemented this to execute within a ScheduledExecutorService and set the executor to have a initial delay of zero and a further delay of 30 seconds

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
`ScheduledFuture sequenceFutre = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(sequenceRunnable, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
```

I have the looping of the array list of lights like this

```
        try {
        while (!pause) {
            for (int i = 0; i < theLights.size(); i++) {
                Light light = theLights.get(i);
                System.out.println(String.format(outputstr, (i + 1), light.turnOn()));
                Thread.sleep(HALF_SECOND_INTERVAL);
                System.out.println(String.format(outputstr, (i + 1), light.turnOff()));
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Error err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The part i am missing here is that the runnable this is wrapped in does not seem to stop at 30 seconds and wait 30 seconds before resuming, which is the requirement.

Can anyone help please? what am i missing?

Comment: Could you provide some additional context concerning the pause variable? How is it set exactly?

Comment: @Lefty, it isn't set per se, its initialised to false and left that way. (no pun intended)

Answer (score 3):

your runnable `run()` method is called for each execution.  you should not use a while loop in your code, you should return from your run method after each sequence completion.

UPDATE:

as the OP indicated, one "run" should be based on a length of time, so your run method should keep track of how long it has been running.  i.e. record the current time at the beginning of the run method and then keep looping until 30 seconds has elapsed, then return from your run method.

Comment: And, in fact, it's called only once if it never returns.

Comment: @jtahlborn this is a straight runnable though, run is void, therefore there is no return.... or should i upgrade that part to a callable and just                                                                   'return;'

Comment: @JBNizet, this is the trap i have found myself in - you will have guessed by new i am reasonably new to concurrent programming - it needs to run indefinately, or are you suggesting that i keep calling get on the Future?

Comment: the requirement is that it runs continually for 30 seconds and then waits for 30 seconds, having applied the suggestions, and thank you for them, it does one iteration of the List then stops and waits until it is called again when it does just one more run of the List....

Comment: @Beer0 - i have updated my answer.  hopefully you have realized at this point that you can return from a void method (or just let control go to the end of the method).

Comment: @jtahlborn, yes i have just added a `return;` i appreciate your suggestion and it is an interesting solution, I was still trying to get the `ScheduledExecutorService` to do this for me though...... it would appear though that i cannot run, indefinately with the while and for loop together, perhaps i need - as you suggest - to pass in the running time, and use a do while loop instead.. thankyou for your help.

Comment: @Beer0 - yes, the ScheduledExecutorService does not help specify _how long_ your code should execute, it only enables you to configure _when_ your code should run.

Comment: @jtahlborn, indeed however it is best practice to use those executors, although in this case it would seem that the solution requires not using them

Comment: @Beer0 - i'm not saying that at all.  it is certainly best practice to use them, and indeed you should be using them for this code.  i'm just saying that you need to do 2 things, but the ScheduledExecutorService only handles one of them for you, you need to handle the other yourself.